# Changed DocumentRoot in httpd.conf, $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] still the same

Tags: php, xampp, document-root

So I changed `DocumentRoot` in my `httpd.conf` files and `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` still seems to be the same on XAMPP. I've restarted the server and the problem still persists. I've change `DocumentRoot` before from the original `xampp/htdocs` folder and it worked fine. Any clues?

Comment: Since it is XAMPP installation, change the root in the XAMPP settins?

Comment: Where can I find this? I thought changing `DocumentRoot` was sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

Note the DOCUMENT_ROOT for PHP might not be the same as of Apache.
DOCUMENT_ROOT is where the PHP file is located. This could be on Document root or through a different directory.

Answer (score 0):

There's another line in the httpd.conf file that needs changing. In my file it was about 30 lines below the DocumentRoot setting. I found it thanks to the preceding comment line

```
#
# This should be changed to whatever you set DocumentRoot to.
#
<Directory "C:/work/htdocs">
```

I just moved the whole htdocs directory so I also had to change a line in the httpd-xampp.conf file as well.

```
<Directory "C:/work/htdocs/xampp">
```